# How to set the background using acrylic brush through C# in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I've tried the following:

```
{
    ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog()
    {
        Title = title,
        Content = text,
        CloseButtonText = closeButtonText
    };
    
    dialog.Background = new AcrylicBrush()
    {
        BackgroundSource = 0,
        TintOpacity = 0.5,
        Opacity = 0.5,  
    };
    
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

P.S. - Sorry for the Russian and my bad English. Thank you in advance

[image: BC SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is well if you can see the button after the content dialog.

The code that I do not use acrylic brush.

```
    private async void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var title = "title";
        var text = "text";
        var closeButtonText = "close";

        ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog()
        {
            Title = title,
            Content = text,
            CloseButtonText = closeButtonText
        };           

        dialog.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 202, 24, 37));

        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

[image]

The code that I use acrylic brush.

```
    private async void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var title = "title";
        var text = "text";
        var closeButtonText = "close";

        ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog()
        {
            Title = title,
            Content = text,
            CloseButtonText = closeButtonText
        };

        if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent(
            "Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.XamlCompositionBrushBase"))
        {
            // check that this API is available on the user’s machine
            dialog.Background = new AcrylicBrush()
            {
                BackgroundSource = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBackgroundSource.HostBackdrop,
                TintOpacity = 0.5,
                FallbackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 202, 24, 37),
                Opacity = 0.5,
            };
        }

        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

[image]

See [Acrylic material - Windows UWP applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic)

[Customize Acrylic Brush in UWP Applications](https://edi.wang/post/2018/3/29/customize-acrylic-uwp)